# R: List with multiple headings - How to split by heading (unequal lines per heading)

Tags: r, list, split, heading

I've a large file that looks like this:

```
Heading1
1 ABC
2 DEF
Heading2
1 GHI
2 JKL
3 MNO
Heading3
1 PQR
2 STU
```

The headings have always the same pattern, but the entries below each heading are different — different number of entries, no common pattern, different number of letters and/or words.

I want to split the one list into multiple lists, i.e. a new list for each heading. How can I solve this?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible sample of your data using dput(), dump() or structure()?

Comment: > dput(test)  
list("Heading1", "1 ABC", "2 DEF", "Heading2", "1 GHI", "2 JKL", "3 MNO", "Heading3", "1 PQR", "2 STU")

Comment: there should have been a line break after dput(test)....

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, much appreciated!

Comment: Not what you asked for exactly, but you can look at [`read.mtable`](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun/reference/read.mtable.html) from "[SOfun](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun)". You'd be able to do `library(SOfun); read.mtable("test.txt", "Heading")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
header_positions <- grepl("^Heading", test)
header_positions

grouping_index <- cumsum(header_positions)
grouping_index

li <- split(test[!header_positions], grouping_index[!header_positions])
li

setNames(li, test[header_positions]) # if you want to have fancy names :)
```

I think the `cumsum(grepl(...))` pattern is very useful for this kind of list splitting tasking.

If you want to write out via `writeLines()` you need to convert the list elements to `character` vectors with `unlist()`:

```
for(n in names(li)) {
  writeLines(unlist(li[[n]]), paste0(n, ".txt"))
}
```

This is another helpful pattern to iterate over the names of a list, so you can access the names directly (for filenames) and use them to index the list (for the file contents).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards grepl & cumsum, this solution is very clear, much appreciated!

Comment: sooo.... I thought it surely would be easy to save each list as separate file with filename = header. But, how? I edited the original question :)

Comment: I don't think you have a list, sounds more like a data frame, what is the original file format you are trying to split up?

Comment: Plain old txt. It's really annoying and looks like the example, just much longer :(

Comment: Got it, no worries there. Are the leading number meant as a rowID?

Comment: ah, the leading numbers are part of the original file content (although not needed), just like in the test example list.

Comment: brilliant, that does it. I was playing around with paste but wasn't aware of unlist. And of course n in double brackets, I'm still getting confused with understanding the data format to get the right info. Anyway, thanks heaps!

Comment: Totally, I stumbled on the single/double bracket indexing writing it too! Such is R, happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
mylist = list("Heading1", "1 ABC", "2 DEF", "Heading2", "1 GHI", "2 JKL", "3 MNO", "Heading3", "1 PQR", "2 STU")
idx = unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) as.numeric(regexpr("heading", x, ignore.case=T))))
idx[which(idx == -1)] = 0
idx = cumsum(idx)
myotherlist = vector("list", max(idx))
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) myotherlist[[idx[i]]] = append(myotherlist[[idx[i]]], mylist[i])
```